# Windows 10 UWP - GridView Items With no DataContext when Not Visible

Tags: c#, windows, gridview, win-universal-app

I have an issue with a GridView in a UWP application that I'm working on...

Items in the GridView load correctly, however items that are out of view (off the page and not visible) do not have a DataContext assigned, and no event ever fires when the DataContext is assigned. Various bindings do work as TextBlocks that are bound get updated, but the the normal event workflow and Loaded events get all strange.

[image: Null DataContext in Loaded Event]

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" Name="SearchGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchItems}" ItemClick="SearchGrid_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:RsrItemGridViewItem />
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

The grids all show correctly, except, for being able to properly delay load some items because the DataContext isn't set at time of load (and a DataContextChanged event isn't fired when the context is updated).

Does anyone have any ideas how to get notified when the control becomes visible? This seems like a notification bug, or there is some binding thing that I'm missing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any ideas how to get notified when the control becomes visible?

You can't use [FrameworkElement.Loaded event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) here to get notify when your `RsrItemGridViewItem` becomes visible, this event occurs when a FrameworkElement has been constructed and added to the object tree, and is ready for interaction.

`GirdView` control implements [UI virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx) for better UI performance, if your `GridView` is bound to a collection of many items, it might download only items 1-50, When the user scrolls near the end of the list, then items 51 – 100 are downloaded and so on. But for example, there are only 20 items now be shown, but it might have loaded 45 items, 25 items could not be seen in this moment.

If you change the default `ItemsPanel` of `GridView` which is `ItemsWrapGrid` to for example `VariableSizedWrapGrid`, `GridView` will lose virtualization, and all items will be loaded at the same time even most of them can not be seen at one moment.

For you problem, I think what you can give a try is calculating the `ScrollViewer`'s VerticalOffset with your `GridView`'s height and the items's count be shown, and then you can know which items are been shown at this moment.

For example here:

```
private ObservableCollection<MyList> list = new ObservableCollection<MyList>();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private double viewheight;

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = FindChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(gridView);
    scrollViewer.ViewChanged += ScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
    viewheight = gridView.ActualHeight;
}

private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    var Y = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
    //calculate here to get the displayed items.
}

public static T FindChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
{
    var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
    queue.Enqueue(root);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        DependencyObject current = queue.Dequeue();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
            var typedChild = child as T;
            if (typedChild != null)
            {
                return typedChild;
            }
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    list.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new MyList { text = "Item " + i });
    }
}
```

Since `GridView` control's layout is adaptive to the app's size, the current displayed count is dynamic, you can try other height based properties (for example each item's height) and the `ScrollViewer`'s VerticalOffset to calculate, there is no ready-made method to get your work done, it's a little complex to calculate, but I think there is no better solution for now.

Comment: After doing some testing with this, what I found out worked (though it's not very clean, and I believe there is a bug with bindings) was to add the custom control to the GridView, then in the grid view adding a `DataContext={Binding}` to the Image I wanted to get notified of an update on.

`<Image DataContext="{Binding}" DataContextChanged="ItemImage_DataContextChanged" />`

The main control doesn't get notified of a DataContext change, but the child elements are notified.

Comment: @Josh， problem is, even it has a DataContext, doesn't mean that item can be seen at that moment.

Comment: Yeah... But I think the real issue is that when the children are receiving DataContextChanged notifications, the parent, bound to the same context isn't receiving those notifications.

In my example above, the RsrItemGridViewItem's children receive a DataContextChanged notification, but the main RsrItemGridViewItem doesn't receive the notification.

Comment: @Josh, DataContextChanged has routing behavior but isn't a true routed event (it does not have a RoutedEvent identifier). Also, it routes from parent to child whereas the true routed events route from child to parent. You can refer to [FrameworkElement.DataContextChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged.aspx). It's not a bug, it is just designed to be so.

Answer (score -1):

After doing some testing with this, what I found out worked (though it's not very clean, and I believe there is a bug with bindings) was to add the custom control to the GridView, then in the grid view adding a `DataContext={Binding}` to the Image I wanted to get notified of an update on.

```
<UserControl ...><Image DataContext="{Binding}" DataContextChanged="ItemImage_DataContextChanged" /></UserControl>
```

The main control doesn't get notified of a DataContext change, but the child elements are notified.